# When a country doesn't recognize another country diplomatically

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request, sentence-structure, sentence-request

In my language, there is a political term which is used to indicate that in diplomatic relationships a country doesn't consider the other country as a legal or true country. The only translation I found for it is: "To recognize a country officially / diplomatically".

But, how shall one say it? Let me ask my question in another way; which one of the following sentences sounds more idiomatic:

> A) (The country) X does not recognize (the country) Y.
>
> B) (The country) X does not recognize (the country) Y officially.
>
> C) (The country) X does not recognize (the country) Y diplomatically.

If there is a more natural way, then please let me know about it.

Comment: **does not recognize** is the correct phrase. Compare: "United States announces that it will recognize communist China (1978)" http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/united-states-announces-that-it-will-recognize-communist-china

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TRomano points out in his comment, "does not recognize" is natural English for this context.  This is course, fairly formal and diplomatic language, and in general would not be used outside of government or politics.

> The United States government did not formally recognize the Communist government of the People's Republic of China until 1979, although it still does not recognize their claim to Taiwan and various other islands in the South Pacific.

Answer (score 0):

(The country) X does not have [diplomatic relations](https://definitions.uslegal.com/d/diplomatic-relations/) with (the country) Y.